# Error while setting up sample data in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2.4.1

[image]I have installed Magento 2.4.1 via composer and got the store and admin panel without any error but when I try to set sample data am getting the below error.

Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogRuleSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallCatalogRuleSampleData for module Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData. Original exception message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.

I have used the below commands to set the sample data.
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
php bin/magento module:enable --all
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Also, I have enabled the developer mode and ran the above command still am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by MySQL 8.

You can see more details in this exact issue reported on [Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30685)

Downgrade your MySQL version and try again.

Comment: I am using MySQL version 8.0.12